# How can I prove that the collection of all (class-)function from a proper class A to a class B is empty?

Tags: set-theory

In MK set theory, I have to show that $B^A = \emptyset$  whenever A is a proper class. A proper class is a class that is not a set i.e. a class that doesn't belong to another class. 
I thought that I could proove it by contradiction. Suppose $B^A \neq \emptyset$, so by Foundation Axiom there is an $ f \in B^A$ such that $f$ and $B^A$ are disjoint but then i'm stuck. Also I don't understant it intuitively : if i take all the ordered pairs (x,y) for all x in A and a fixed y in B, meaning the function that sends everything in a fixed element in B, could such a class-function belong to $B^A$ ?

EDIT: Just got it! Suppose there is an $f \in B^A$. Then $f$ is a set. $ x \in A$ implise $x \in \{x\} \in (x,y) \in f$ then $x \in (\cup(\cup f)) $. Then A is a subclass of a set, read A belongs to a set (the power set of $\cup \cup f$). a contradiction. Is that a correct proof ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I thought that I could proove it by contradiction. Suppose $B^A \neq \emptyset$, so by Foundation Axiom there is an $ f \in B^A$ such that f and $B^A$ are disjoint but then i'm stuck. Also I don't understant it intuitively : if i take all the ordered pairs (x,y) for all x in A and a fixed y in B, meaning the function that sends everything in a fixed element in B, could such a class-function belong to $B^A$ ?

Comment: The idea is that you edit your question in order to show your effort, not that you display it in a comment.

Comment: oh i'm sorry, thank you!

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct. In simpler terms, the domain of a function is a set if and only if the function is a set. Therefore, if $f$ is an element of $B^A$, $f$ is a set, so $A$ has to be a set.

Comment: So, there are class-functions with domain a proper class (the aleph function for example) but thoose functions are proper-class so there is no collection of such functions. Am i right?